# delta_import from MongoDB to SOLR in Windows

Tags: query-by-example

I am new to SOLR  & successfully managed to made full-import from mongoDB to SOLR in windows but when i tried to perform delta-import it was not done and there is no log information also found can any suggest me to complete delta import from mongoDB to SOLR 6 in windows
My data-config.xml as follows

```
 <entity  processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
query="{Name:'Erik'}"
deltaImportQuery="{'id':{$eq:'${dih.request.id}'}}"
deltaQuery="{'UpdateDate':{$gt:'${dih.last_index_time}'}}"
collection="sample1"   
datasource="MyMongo"
transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" name="sample_entity10">
<field column="_id"  name="id" hashObjectId="true"/>
<field column="UpdateDate" name="UpdateDate" mongoField="UpdateDate"/>
<field column="EmpNumber" name="EmployeeNumber" mongoField="EmpNumber" stored="true"/>
</entity>
```

and my document in mongodb loks like

```
{
        "UpdateDate":"2016-06-06T11:56:26.709Z",
        "EmployeeNumber":854665,
        "id":"575564ea2f91dd2db616972f",
        "Name":"Erik",
        "_version_":1536393867196104704},
}
```

Comment: Could you add more details about your problem and what you have tried?

Comment: Can Any one give me a suggestion for the above mentioned problem